# What is the proper way of executing multiple queries with one function call in MySQL Connector C++ API?

Tags: c++, api, mysql-connector

I'm new to MySQL, also their C++ **API** and I'm having a trouble executing multiple queries at once instead of calling the same function twice, I mean my queries are kinda linked and logically they should be executed at once.

I used to do so for example

```
sql::ResultSet* sqlExecute(std::string Query)
try
{
    sql::ResultSet *res;
    res = statement->executeQuery(Query);
    return res;
}
catch (sql::SQLException& e)
{
    if (e.getErrorCode())
        outc("%c%s: [SQL %c%d%c]%c %s\n", c_gray, my_time("WARN"), c_dark_purple, e.getErrorCode(), c_gray, c_dark_red, e.what());
    return 0;
}
```

and call it like this (twice)

```
sqlExecute("alter table ###.players AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;");
sqlExecute("insert into ###.players (name, username, password) values('Random Name', 'imrandom', 'this should be random too');");
```

but when I try to execute them with just one function call separated by `;`

```
sqlExecute("alter table ###.players AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;insert into ###.players (name, username, password) values('Random Name', 'imrandom', 'this should be random too');");
```

I get exception

---

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into ###.players (name, username, password) values('Random Name', 'imrand' at line 1

---

In MySQL Workbench, I can execute multiple queries at once. Why not in the API too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ability to execute multiple statements separated by semicolons depends on the [`CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-connect-options.html) connection property being enabled:

```
sql::ConnectOptionsMap options;
options["CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS"] = true;

sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver = sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver::get_mysql_driver_instance();
sql::Connection *con = driver->connect(options);
```

Comment: I didn't know there's such a thing. It worked, thank you :)